# Remove old kernels on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, kernel, yum, rpm, dnf

On CentOS 7.X I use the following command to clean up unused old kernel:

```
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1
```

But it no longer works on CentOS 8.X, does anyone know the correct command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
dnf remove --oldinstallonly --setopt installonly_limit=1
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
1. rpm -qa kernel // lists kernels
2. rpm -e kernel_name // on which kernel you want to remove
```

This should also automatically remove grub entries for you.

Comment: According to the [official DNF documentation](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html#installonly-limit-label) the minimum value for the `installonly_limit` is 2.